# How to pass props(or parameter) to class extends components

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm new to react and I'm having a hard time passing props/parameter to Class that extends Component

1. Here is my button that navigate to class with components

   ```
   <Button variant="primary" type="button" 
           onClick={event =>  window.location.href=/editprofile} cpCode={id}> Edit</Button>
   ```
2. Here is my class that will received the parameter/props

```
export default class AddProfile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.setBirthDate = this.setBirthDate.bind(this);
    this.onChangeFirstName = this.onChangeFirstName.bind(this);
    this.onChangeMiddleName = this.onChangeMiddleName.bind(this);
    this.onChangeLastName = this.onChangeLastName.bind(this);
    this.onChangeAlias = this.onChangeAlias.bind(this);
    this.onChangeGender = this.onChangeGender.bind(this);
    this.submitProfile = this.submitProfile.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      cpCode: '',
      firstname: '',
      middlename: '',
      lastname: '',
      alias: '',
      gender: '',
      birthdate: '',
      hasErrors: false,
      errors: {
          firstnameError: '',
          middlenameError: '',
          lastnameError: '',
          aliasError: '',
          genderError: '',
          birthdateError: '',
      },
      responseMessage: ''
    }
  }
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is the issue? Where are you passing any props to `AddProfile` component? Where are you reading from props? We need more context. See also [Components and Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

Comment: I want to call cpCode props in the AddProfile class, but the problem is i don't know to use the props cpCode inside the AddProfile class.



export default function ProfileAccounts({ cpCode : cpCode, ...rest }) extends Component{

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that comment. If you need to pass props to `AddProfile` just pass props to `AddProfile` like you would *any other* React component, i.e. `<AddProfile prop1={...} prop2={...} ...etc... />`. `cpCode` appears to be in `AddProfile`'s state though.

Answer (score 0):

Passing props to a class component (a.k.a "Class extends Component"), works the same way as passing props to a functional component:

```
<YourComponent propA={"foo"} propB={55} />
```

The difference is, on the class component, you read `this.props`, while on the functional component, you read the `props` of the function (ex: `function YourComponent(props)`).
You can read more in the [official documentation about props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

To get the props "from your button to your component", is a different issue, and can be addressed in multiple ways. One common way, would be to do do a `setState`:

```
const [cpCode, setCpCode] = useState();

...

return (
   <>
     <Button onClick={() => setCpCode(id)}>Edit</Button>
     <AddProfile cpCode={cpCode} />
   </>
);
```

If you need to render a different page, you could pass your code through query parameters:

```
<Button onClick={() =>  window.location.href=`/editprofile?cpCode=${id}`}> Edit</Button>
```

```
function ASimpleFunctionalComponent() {
  const cpCode = window.location.href.split('=')[1]
  return <AddProfile cpCode={} />
}
```

Notice that you could also do the `const cpCode = window.href.split('=')[1]` inside your `<AddProfile />`, the above example was meant to clearly indicate how you can pass props.

Also note that if you are using `react-router`, instead of reading with `window.href.split('=')[1]`, you should use `useParams`. Here is the [documentation for useParams](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams)

Comment: But how I may suppose to call or user cpCode inside AddProfile class?